# Jhipster - Backend URL in Angular 2 Client

Tags: jhipster

I have created a separate project ie the client and the server on different projects. How do I point the URL of my client APIs to the remote server?

ENV - Production

I'm using Angular 2

Comment: actually, after reading your question twice, I don't get it. What is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your entity.service.js, you should have something like this :

```
function Entity ($resource) {
    var resourceUrl =  'api/entities/:id';
```

simply change the last line with :

```
     var resourceUrl =  'http://your.serveur.url/api/entities/:id';
```

You may have to enable cross posting if your server isn't in the same domain
https://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/

Answer (score 0):

you need to run jhipster-registry, clone this https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry
and run mvnw and next run your microservice and gateway